# WTForms DateTimeField returning True not matter input

Tags: python, flask-wtforms, wtforms

I am struggling to understand why WTForms always validates my input even when it doesn't match the default input format stated in the docs. The docs say the default format is

`class wtforms.fields.DateTimeField(default field arguments, format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')`

but my code always returned true

```
from wtforms import Form, validators
from wtforms.fields import DateTimeField

class InputForm(Form):
        timestamp = DateTimeField('TimeStamp', validators=[validators.DataRequired()])

form = InputForm(timestamp='lmao')
form.validate()
# True
```

Can someone explain this behavior to me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To put it simply, whether the value you pass to the field can be coerced to a datetime isn't being checked as the validator that you have supplied only checks for existence of the data, not the type.

The `DateTimeField` does ensure that a value can be coerced to a datetime, but only if the value comes from a form. As you can see below, passing a value in to the form constructor via kwargs (`timestamp='lmao'`) isn't passed through the same test.

Looking at the definition of the [`DateTimeField`](https://github.com/wtforms/wtforms/blob/master/src/wtforms/fields/core.py#L820-L846), the only method that has custom handling to do with the field being a datetime field is the `process_formdata()` method (also `_value()` but that is used by widgets to render fields):

```py
class DateTimeField(Field):
    """
    A text field which stores a `datetime.datetime` matching a format.
    """

    widget = widgets.TextInput()

    def __init__(
        self, label=None, validators=None, format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", **kwargs
    ):
        super(DateTimeField, self).__init__(label, validators, **kwargs)
        self.format = format

    def _value(self):
        if self.raw_data:
            return " ".join(self.raw_data)
        else:
            return self.data and self.data.strftime(self.format) or ""

    def process_formdata(self, valuelist):
        if valuelist:
            date_str = " ".join(valuelist)
            try:
                self.data = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_str, self.format)
            except ValueError:
                self.data = None
                raise ValueError(self.gettext("Not a valid datetime value"))
```

When you instantiate a `Form` object, the form's `process()` method is called which calls the `process()` method of each of the forms fields and passes the `formdata` (which in this case is `None`) and a value for the field if one can be found (in this case, `'lmao'`).

As you can see, there is no `process()` method defined on the `DateTimeField` definition above, so it calls `Field.process()`:

```py
    def process(self, formdata, data=unset_value):
        """
        Process incoming data, calling process_data, process_formdata as needed,
        and run filters.
        If `data` is not provided, process_data will be called on the field's
        default.
        Field subclasses usually won't override this, instead overriding the
        process_formdata and process_data methods. Only override this for
        special advanced processing, such as when a field encapsulates many
        inputs.
        """
        self.process_errors = []
        if data is unset_value:
            try:
                data = self.default()
            except TypeError:
                data = self.default

        self.object_data = data

        try:
            self.process_data(data)
        except ValueError as e:
            self.process_errors.append(e.args[0])

        if formdata is not None:
            if self.name in formdata:
                self.raw_data = formdata.getlist(self.name)
            else:
                self.raw_data = []

            try:
                self.process_formdata(self.raw_data)
            except ValueError as e:
                self.process_errors.append(e.args[0])

        try:
            for filter in self.filters:
                self.data = filter(self.data)
        except ValueError as e:
            self.process_errors.append(e.args[0])
```

In this method, the parameter `data` is `'lmao'`, and `formdata` is `None`. You can see that the call to `process_formdata()` is guarded by the `if formdata is not None:` conditional, and so the custom handling for the field defined on `DateTimeField` is only run on data that comes from a form.

```py
from werkzeug import MultiDict

form = InputForm(formdata=MultiDict([("timestamp", "lmao")]))

print(form.timestamp.raw_data)  # ['lmao']
print(form.timestamp.process_errors)  # ['Not a valid datetime value']
print(form.validate())  # False
```

This means that you are responsible for the validity of values that you pass in to your form fields through kwargs to the form constructor.

Comment: Thanks so much for that thorough answer.